# Python any(iterable) and all(iterable) without short-circuiting and with side-effects

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def evAnd(v, *predicates):
    satisfied=True
    for f in predicates:
        if not f(v):
            satisfied=False
            # log: f,v->False in a map and other side effects
        else:
            # log: f,v->True in a map and other side effects
    return satisfied


def evOr(v, *predicates):
    satisfied=False
    for f in predicates:
        if f(v):
            satisfied=True
            # log: f,v->True in a map and other side effects
        else:
            # log: f,v->False in a map and other side effects
    return satisfied
```

What's the Pythonic way to unify the above in a single function? (as there is considerable side-effect code where the log messages are placed) Notice the presence of side effects and the need to evaluate the outcome for **all** predicates without the short-circuiting of [any](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [all](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

### solution based on accepted answer

So, here's what I did in the end based on the accepted answer:

```
def adorn(predicate):
    def rv(v):
        rvi = predicate(v)
        if rvi:
            print "%s is satisfied for value %d" % (predicate.__name__, v)
            # any other side effects
        else:
            print "%s is not satisfied for value %d" % (predicate.__name__, v)
            # any other side effects
        return rvi
    return rv


def my_all(n, predicates):
    return reduce(operator.and_, map( lambda x : x(n), map(adorn, predicates)), True)

def my_any(n, predicates):
    return reduce(operator.or_, map( lambda x : x(n) , map(adorn, predicates)), False)
```

It can be tested with:

```
def even(n):
    return n%2==0

def odd(n):
    return n%2!=0

print my_all(3, [even, odd])
print my_any(4, [even, odd])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply

```
reduce(operator.and_, seq)
```

for "all", and

```
reduce(operator.or_, seq)
```

for "any".

Comment: `operator.and_` and `operator.or_` are bitwise operations.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, if you pass a generator expression to `any` or `all` it would be short-circuited but if you make it a LC and pass it to both these built-ins, short-circuits wont be possible and you would get the effect that you wanted to pursue

The following demonstration is self explanatory and can be adapted to your problem

```
>>> count = 0
>>> def foo(n):
    global count
    count += 1
    return n%2

>>> any(foo(n) for n in range(10))
True
>>> count
2
>>> count = 0
>>> any([foo(n) for n in range(10)])
True
>>> count
10
```

**As suggested by Blender, it might create a list that whould be discarded. A more generator oriented solution would be as follows**

Another way to look into this problem (at least for generators) is,  you want to consume the rest of the iterable if short-circuited by `any` or `all`. You can easily do so, by partly borrowing the  [consume itertools recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
>>> count
0
>>> it = (foo(n) for n in range(10))
>>> any(it)
True
>>> collections.deque(it, maxlen = 0)
deque([], maxlen=0)
>>> count
10
```

And here are two version of any and all which would not short-circuit. Feel free to give a meaningful names to these functions (which I am really bad with)

```
>>> def all_noss(expr):
    it = iter(expr)
    result = any(it)
    collections.deque(it, maxlen = 0)
    return result

>>> def any_noss(expr):
    it = iter(expr)
    result = any(it)
    collections.deque(it, maxlen = 0)
    return result
```

Comment: The problem with the list comprehension is that it creates a list in-memory, which isn't always desirable. If memory wasn't a problem, `any(list(iterable))` would work perfectly.

Comment: If memory is a concern, we could use generator and reduce as my answer proposed.

Comment: @HuiZheng: You can see the second part of my answer which addresses this issue

Answer (score 1):

You may take use of `reduce`:

```
def evAnd(v, *predicates):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, [f(v) for f in predicates])

def evOr(v, *predicates):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x or y, [f(v) for f in predicates])
```

Or take use of `all` or `any`:

```
def evAnd(v, *predicates):
    return all([f(v) for f in predicates])

def evOr(v, *predicates):
    return any([f(v) for f in predicates])
```

Since the above methods create a list comprehension, all predicates WILL be evaluated without short-circuit.

**UPDATE**:

The shortcoming of list comprehensions is they create list in-memory, if that's your concern, we can use generator instead:

```
def evAnd(v, *predicates):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, (f(v) for f in predicates))

def evOr(v, *predicates):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x or y, (f(v) for f in predicates))
```

This time we have to use `reduce`, while `all` or `any` will have short-circuit which is not desirable.

Reminded by @NPE, we can replace lambda with operator:

```
def evAnd(v, *predicates):
    return reduce(operator.and_,  (f(v) for f in predicates))

def evOr(v, *predicates):
    return reduce(operator.or_,  (f(v) for f in predicates))
```